# ValueError at /sendrequest/jacob Cannot assign "'jacob'": "ConnectRequest.receiver" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am making a friend request feature and i got this error
this is my models.py for friend request

```
class ConnectRequest(models.Model):
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="receiver")
choice=(
    ("Accepted","Accepted"),
    ("Declined","Declined"),
    ("Pending","Pending")
)
status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=choice,blank=True)
```

this is my views.py

```
def sendrequest(request,receiver):
sender=request.user
connection=ConnectRequest(sender=sender,receiver=receiver,status="Pending")
connection.save()
return redirect("buddylist")
```

Comment: what is the value that you have on the `receiver` argument?
because the error is clear: `“ConnectRequest.receiver” must be a “User” instance`
I guess you have a string or any other thing, it should be a `User` instance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that is your `views.py` and not `urls.py`

the `receiver` parameter to that view function is just going to be an ID from the URL.  You need this to GET the receiver from the database:

```
def sendrequest(request,receiver):
    receiver_user = User.objects.get(id=receiver)
    sender=request.user
    connection=ConnectRequest(sender=sender,
        receiver=receiver_user,
        status="Pending"
    )
    connection.save()
    return redirect("buddylist")
```

Comment: thanks Laurel i got your point but still i am not able to get my desired output

Comment: Can you show your actual `urls.py`. I want to see where `sendrequest` is defined.

Comment: https://github.com/Alphonse-03/codebuddy  please check it its more clear here actually i have  a profile models and i am extracting the values from profile model